# How To create Multiple Columns From Values of The Same Column?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, merge, multiple-columns

I Have A DataFrame , & I Want to Create New Columns Based o The Values of The Same Column , And At Each of This Column I want The Values To  Be The Sum of repetition of ***Plate*** over the Time.

So I have This DataFrame:

```
   Val_Tra.Head():

                             Plate                          EURO    
   Timestamp                            
   2013-11-01 00:00:00               NaN                    NaN
   2013-11-01 01:00:00  dcc2f657e897ffef752003469c688381    0.0 
   2013-11-01 02:00:00  a5ac0c2f48ea80707621e530780139ad    6.0
```

So I Have The ***EURO*** Column That Looks Like This:

```
   Veh_Tra.EURO.value_counts():

   5    1590144
   6     745865
   4     625512
   0     440834
   3     243800
   2      40664
   7      14207
   1       4301
```

And This My Desired Output:

```
                                       Plate               EURO_1    EURO_2    EURO_3    EURO_4    EURO_5    EURO_6   EURO_7    
   Timestamp                            
   2013-11-01 00:00:00               NaN                    NaN      NaN        NaN       NaN        NaN        NaN     NaN
   2013-11-01 01:00:00  dcc2f657e897ffef752003469c688381    1.0      NaN        NaN        NaN       NaN        NaN     NaN 
   2013-11-01 02:00:00  a5ac0c2f48ea80707621e530780139ad    NaN      NaN        1.0        NaN       NaN        NaN     NaN
```

So Basically , What I Want , Is The Sum in Which Each Time That a ***Plate*** Value repeats Itself on a  Specific Type of ***Euro*** over a specific Time.

Any Suggestions Would Be Much Appreciated , Thank U.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is more like a `get_dummies` problem

```
s=df.dropna().EURO.astype(int).astype(str).str.get_dummies().add_prefix('EURO')
df=pd.concat([df,s],axis=1,sort=True)
df
Out[259]: 
                                               Plate  EURO  EURO0  EURO6
2013-11-0100:00:00                               NaN   NaN    NaN    NaN
2013-11-0101:00:00  dcc2f657e897ffef752003469c688381   0.0    1.0    0.0
2013-11-0102:00:00  a5ac0c2f48ea80707621e530780139ad   6.0    0.0    1.0
```